# Exclude file from project via msbuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

In my .csproj file, I am creating directories containing files, and these directories are being created in the main project directory as intended. For certain reasons, I cannot generate these directories in bin\debug. However, I do not want the files generated in the directories to be included in the project, as I do not want them to be checked in.

How can I exclude the files from my project automatically through msbuild?

For reference, I have tried the following, and though the files get generated as expected, they are still being added to the project unintentionally:

```cs
<Target Name="BuildThings" AfterTargets="Build" BeforeTargets="GatherStagingFiles" Inputs="@(Compile)" Outputs="$(GeneratedFilesDirectory)">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" Command="$(ToolPath) buildpackage -InputDir:$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutDir) -OutputDir:$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(GeneratedFilesDirectory)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="HideFiles" DependsOnTargets="BuildThings">
  <ItemGroup>
    <GeneratedFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(GeneratedFilesDirectory)\file.txt">
      <InProject>false</InProject>
    </GeneratedFiles>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Is this a "full framework" project, .net core / SDK-based? (=> how are they automatically included if not .NET Core / standard / SDK-based?)

Comment: Is the folder always the same name? I mean, can you define it in the `.csproj` file before the build?